# Display String From Text File in a Label Box in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

So I am trying to make a code where the user inputs an ID number and receives the line of text that the ID corresponds to. I am having trouble with the code as I am unable to display the result (or correct result) in a label box.

For example:

If I type in ID 1, it displays the data that corresponds to ID 2, ID 2 corresponds to ID 3 and ID 3 ends the loop (there are only 3 records in the data currently).

I have included my code below

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Filename = "NamesAndAges.txt"
    FileOpen(1, Filename, OpenMode.Input,,,)

    Dim ID As Integer
    ID = txtSearch.Text

    Dim Found As Boolean
    Found = False

    Do While Not EOF(1) And Found = False

        If LineInput(1).Contains(ID) Then
            lblDisplaySearch.Text = LineInput(1)
            Found = True
        Else MsgBox("Not Found")

        End If
    Loop

    FileClose(1)
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, would also really appreciate if anyone could explain the code they use as I am still a visual basic beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `LineInput(1)`, it reads a line, so you're reading a line and checking if it contains ID then reading another line and setting `lblDisplaySearch.Text` to that value.

Try something like this:

```
Dim line As String

Do While Not EOF(1) And Found = False
    line = LineInput(1)

    If line.Contains(ID) Then
        lblDisplaySearch.Text = line
        Found = True
    Else MsgBox("Not Found")

    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest simplifying this code, by using [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Filename = "NamesAndAges.txt"
    Dim line = File.ReadLines(Filename).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains(txtSearch.Text))
    If line Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Not Found")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    lblDisplaySearch.Text = line
End Sub
```

The primary advantage is that you don't need to manage the `Do While` loop. Instead, you are passing the match condition (`Function(x) x.Contains(txtSearch.Text)`) to the `FirstOrDefault` method, which internally will find the first line matching the condition and return it, or return `Nothing` if it's not found.

**`For Each` and `IEnumerable`**

VB.NET allows you to loop over a set of items without knowing or caring about the index within the set. For example:

```
For Each x As String In File.ReadLines(Filename)
    'do something with the line, which is now in x
Next
```

In order to use `For Each` with an object, that object has to [implement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z6hzchx.aspx) a specific [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9xt0sdd.aspx) — the [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

[**Interfaces**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9xt0sdd.aspx)

Interfaces guarantee that a given object has, or implements, specific members. In this case, if an object implements the `IEnumerable` interface, that means it has a [`GetEnumerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which the `For Each` uses under the hood.

[**IEnumerable(Of T)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

The object returned from `File.ReadLines` implements another more advanced [generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx) interface called `IEnumerable(Of T)`. With this interface, the compiler can figure out automatically that each step of the `For Each` will be parsing a string, and we don't need to specify it as a string:

```
For Each x In File.ReadLines(Filename)
    'x is known to be a String here
Next
```

[**Lambda expressions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx)

The condition "the line which contains the search text" is written as a **lambda expression**, which (in this case) is made into a method without an explicit name or definition. This is convenient, because we don't have to write this:

```
Function ContainsCondition(line As String, toFind As String) As Boolean
    Return line.Contains(toFind)
End Function`
```

every time we want to express a condition this way.

**Type of `x` in the condition**

Because `File.ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`, in this case an `IEnumerable(Of String)`, the compiler can figure out that the condition is working on strings, so we don't have to specify that `x` is a string within the condition.

Comment: What are the advantages of using this over my current code? Also could you briefly explain to me the 'FirstOrDefault(Function(x)' section of the file.readlines - I'm still very new to visual basic and really want to improve my knowledge. Thanks

Comment: @v_kns I've updated my answer with some more information.